# Conditional forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | 22 | 44 | 1 |
| nan | nan | nan | 5 |
| 517 | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | nan | nan |
| nan | -33 | nan | nan |
| nan | nan | 8 | nan |
| nan | nan | nan | 0 |

I have the above dataframe, df, and I am preforming a forward fill. BUT if data4 ==5 I want to delete all the rows until the value in data4 changes.
If I ffill and just filter out data4 !=5 then I end up getting values like 517 in the row with data4==0 which I don't want.
The below gets rid of the row that contains 5 but not if another column contained a value while data4 was 5

```
filtereddf = df[df.data4 !=5]
```

I want the result to be:

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | 22 | 44 | 1 |
| 88 | 22 | 44 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
# Just forward fill the column you want to filter
df['data4'] = df.data4.ffill()

# Filter by column
df = df.loc[df.data4 != 5]

# Fill all the columns
df.ffill()
```

Output

```
   data1  data2  data3  data4
0   88.0   22.0   44.0    1.0
6   88.0   22.0   44.0    0.0
```

Comment: You can do it in one shot: `df[df['data4'].ffill().ne(5)].ffill()` ;)

Comment: Yes, we can do that. It's a matter of better readability vs efficiency. I prefer one-liners, when suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Try just ffilling data4 first, then remove rows where it's 5:

```
df['data4'] = df['data4'].ffill()
df.loc[df['data4'] != 5].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ffill specific column data4 first.

```
df['data4'] = df['data4'].ffill()
```

|  | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 88.0 | 22.0 | 44.0 | 1.0 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 5.0 |
| 2 | 517.0 | NaN | NaN | 5.0 |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 5.0 |
| 4 | NaN | -33.0 | NaN | 5.0 |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | 8.0 | 5.0 |
| 6 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |

Filter where data4 is not 5, then ffill all columns.

```
filtereddf = df[df['data4'] != 5]
filtereddf.ffill()
```

|  | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 88.0 | 22.0 | 44.0 | 1.0 |
| 6 | 88.0 | 22.0 | 44.0 | 0.0 |

Comment: same answer as the other two…